An elementalist manga where female lead goes to past
I don't remember the name of the manga, but the female lead travels back in time. In her past life, she was sacrificed for her brother because she didn't manifest water powers. After traveling back in time, she develops incredibly strong water magic and forms a pact with the Spirit King. She also helps cure the male lead's curse, which made him blind.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

I copy pasted your question into Google and found this, seems like a decent match
I was the Real Owner of Elheim

Synopsis I Was the Real Owner of Elheim “This time, I will abandon the Elheim ducal house.” A scion of the water noble lineage, the disgraced aristocrat Riarte Elheim. Forced into execution by his twin brother Rian, she awakens to find herself three years before the day of his execution. Returning to life, Riarte seeks to leave the family that killed her. Her path to escape leads her to Michael Burch, the son of a rival family. Can Riarte use Michael to leave her own family? “Riarte, I will give you everything.” But this relationship takes an unexpected turn… With vengeance against the family that forced death upon her, awakening as the ‘true master,’ Riarte’s saga unfolds into a bitter tale of revenge.


Sacrificed
Water magic
Spirits

